# How to download and later install a Chrome plugin?

Tags: google-chrome, plugins, extension

Some of our users use Chrome as their browser. I've recently received the quest from one user to install a particular extension (a password plugin) in his Chrome browser. The user itself cannot install the extension, because it cannot be downloaded on his computer (due to internet access restrictions).

I'm not a Chrome user, so I thought I could simply download the plugin and install it on the user's computer. But when I visit the page to download the plugin, I can only add it to my own Chrome browser (which is not what I want).

How can I download this plugin and install it in the browser of this particular user?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the Chrome Web Store page for the plugin in question.

Scroll down to where the developer's website is listed (they usually are).

Visit the dev's website (more often than not GitHub or some other such place).

Download the .crx file from there (EDIT: it'll probably come under in a compressed format).

Upload it or copy it onto the end-users PC, or zip it and send it via email.

Start Remote Assistance from your PC and connect to his/her PC

Install the plug-in/extension by going to chrome://extensions/ in Chrome, then drag-drop the .crx file onto the page, and wait for install to complete.

EDIT: alternately, you can install on your own version of Chrome this extension (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/get-crx/dijpllakibenlejkbajahncialkbdkjc/) that will let you get a .crx version of any other extension present on the Chrome Web Store, via contextual menu in the extension's page.

Comment: There is only one download link on the developer's website, and it points to the Chrome Web Store, but I'll try your second suggestion and download it on my own install. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: OK, let us know how it went!

Comment: Thanks to the link you posted I was able to download the .crx version from my own Chrome, and install it for the user. Thank you very much!

Comment: Hey, glad to help! Have a nice day!